Android & Kotlin - Add APN Programmatically as Normal App
Currently I have an app written in Kotlin & it is live on store.
I also want to add extra info that my app has carrier priviledge for some eSIM activation purposes, just in case may it is necessary information for the question I will ask.
I want to add my APN settings programmatically. As I researched in official documents, it is possible by using ContentResolver provided by system. I also found some code snippets like that. But commonly I see that I need WRITE_APN_SETTINGS permission. As I searched on another official website, my app should be a system app.
My question; how can I convert my app to a system app? It is important to note that my app is currently live.
As I check from another answer in here, I understand that my app should be ROM spesific. Is this correct? If yes, shall I do bureaucracy with Google or all Android phone manufacturers?
Thank you so much for all valuable information!

a system app is compiled with the OS and typically signed with the platform key.

@tyczj so you mean that there is NO way because app should be build & signed "from zero" via the platform's (I mean Xiaomi's or Samsung's OS) key? Can you explain more ?

correct, unless you are able to sign with the correct key the only other way would be root. system apps are not meant to be created by just anyone

@tyczj Isn't there a way to get it signed with those platform keys, through any bureaucracy between my current company and manifacturers? And why does this have to be "from zero"? Is it because my app is already signed with my own key and is live?
